# What Houses was the Sorting Hat deliberating between for Minerva McGonagall's sorting?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

The Pottermore article on [Hatstall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hatstall) includes the following passage:

> The only true Hatstalls known personally to Harry Potter were Minerva McGonagall and Peter Pettigrew.

It's obvious that for Peter Pettigrew the Sorting Hat would have been debating between Gryffindor and Slytherin, and ended up choosing Gryffindor.

Professor McGonagall ended up in Gryffindor, so what other House was the Hat trying to decide whether or not to put her in?

Comment: FYI, Flitwick was *not quite* a hatstall; since the hat took <5 minutes, then his sorting wasn't considered one. As with McGonagall, the hat vacillated between Ravenclaw and Gryffindor. source: HP wiki article on Flitwick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Ravenclaw

From her [Pottermore profile](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall):

> Minerva drew unusual attention to herself on her very first evening, when she was revealed to be a Hatstall. After five and a half minutes, the Sorting Hat, which had been vacillating between the houses of Ravenclaw and Gryffindor, placed Minerva in the latter.

Comment: Thank you, I hate not having access to Pottermore due to overzealous access filters.

Comment: Now if there were a house for arse-kickers, she would have gone in there.